# How to configure rxvt-unicode to behave similar to gnome-terminal? (or other's from xfce/mate)

Tags: urxvt

Trying out rxvt-unicode, I've found there are so many differences to (gnome-terminal / xfce4-terminal / roxterm / terminator) that its hard to get used to.

What is a good minimal configuration that starts of with similar defaults to gnome terminal (or one of the others, I'm just using this as a reference).

- Key bindings (copy-paste, new tab?)
- Click on URL's
- Scrolling behavior
- Scaling fonts
- Similar colors

For anyone not wanting to someone elses entire configuration, just setup similar basics so its not uncomfortable.

Answer (score 8):

Attempt to answer own question:
Matches gnome-shell, with grey on black colors set.

Details:

- RMB to launch URL (to allow regular LMB/MMB paste).
- Ctrl-Shift-C/V for copy-paste.
- Ctrl +/- to zoom fonts, 0 reset (requires plugin).
- Ctrl-L performs full reset and clear.

Config:

```
! Extensions
! ==========
!
! - matcher,selection-to-clipboard: for clicking on URLs
! - font-size: for scaling fonts
!   https://github.com/majutsushi/urxvt-font-size/blob/master/font-size
!
URxvt.perl-ext-common: default,matcher,selection-to-clipboard,font-size


! Fonts
! =====
URxvt.font: xft:Monospace:size=12
URxvt.allow_bold: true


! Scrolling
! =========
URxvt.saveLines: 10000
URxvt.scrollBar: true
URxvt.scrollstyle: rxvt
URxvt.scrollBar_floating: true
URxvt.scrollColor: #aaaaaa
URxvt.scrollBar_right: true
URxvt.thickness: 12

! Scroll locking
URxvt.scrollTtyOutput:      false
URxvt.scrollWithBuffer:     true
URxvt.scrollTtyKeypress:    true


! Interaction
! ===========

! allow filepaths to select as one, otherwise delimit
URxvt.cutchars: "\"(),<>[]{}|'`"

! For clickable urls (RMB), not an exact match to gnome-shell.
URxvt.url-launcher: xdg-open
URxvt.matcher.button: 3


! Key Bindings
! ============

! Copy/Paste, same keys as gnome-terminal
! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884093
! Disable ISO 14755 unicode input so we can use Ctrl-Shift bindings
URxvt.iso14755:        false
URxvt.iso14755_52:     false
! Disable Ctrl-Alt-c & Ctrl-Alt-v bindings (optional)
URxvt.keysym.C-M-c:    builtin-string:
URxvt.keysym.C-M-v:    builtin-string:
! Bind Ctrl-Shift-c & Ctrl-Shift-v to copy and paste
! I dont know why, but I needed to use hex keysym values to get it to work
URxvt.keysym.C-S-0x43: eval:selection_to_clipboard
URxvt.keysym.C-S-0x56: eval:paste_clipboard

URxvt.keysym.Home: \033[H
URxvt.keysym.End:  \033[F

! match vte/xterm
URxvt.keysym.Control-Up:    \033[1;5A
URxvt.keysym.Control-Down:  \033[1;5B
URxvt.keysym.Control-Left:  \033[1;5D
URxvt.keysym.Control-Right: \033[1;5C

! clear the scrollback
URxvt.keysym.Control-l: command:\033c

! scale fonts
URxvt.keysym.C-S-plus: font-size:increase
URxvt.keysym.C-KP_Add: font-size:increase
URxvt.keysym.C-S-underscore: font-size:decrease
URxvt.keysym.C-KP_Subtract: font-size:decrease
URxvt.keysym.C-0: font-size:reset
URxvt.keysym.C-KP_0: font-size:reset


! Theme/Colors
! ============

URxvt.fading: 0

URxvt.cursorColor: #AAAAAA
URxvt.cursorBlink: 1
URxvt.cursorUnderline: 1

URxvt.background: black
URxvt.foreground: gray

!! Tango Colors
!
!! black dark/light
URxvt.color0: #171A1B
URxvt.color8: #555753

!! red dark/light
URxvt.color1: #CC0000
URxvt.color9: #FF0000

!! green dark/light
URxvt.color2: #00DD00
URxvt.color10: #00FF00

!! yellow dark/light
URxvt.color3: #DDDD00
URxvt.color11: #FFFF00

!! blue dark/light
URxvt.color4: #8888FF
URxvt.color12: #AAAAFF

!! magenta dark/light
URxvt.color5: #75507B
URxvt.color13: #AD7FA8

!! cyan dark/light
URxvt.color6: #06989A
URxvt.color14: #34E2E2

!! white dark/light
URxvt.color7: #D3D7CF
URxvt.color15: #EEEEEC
```

Comment: this worked for me after replacing everything that looked like `URxvt.keysym.*` with `URxvt*keysym.*` ( star instead of dot )